# Damp weather and kitty litter

Tags: cats, weather

So for the last 2 weeks, it's been extremely damp weather here with a relative humidity of about 90%.

There are also 2 other things which are happening since the last 2 weeks.

- Kitty litter is getting consumed really fast - at twice the speed as before. The litter seems damp all the day & when I scoop, more litter is getting scooped out every day.
- The smell of ammonia is strong in the litter. It wasn't so before 2 weeks. Though I can smell the ammonia only when I am scooping - not otherwise - it's not strong enough to permeate the space around the box or anything.

Are these 2 things related to the dampness & humidity? What can be done cheaply to fix this?

I use clumping litter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't live in an extremely humid climate (max around 50%) but what I would try is:

- Non-clumping cat litter - this litter is not designed to absorb moisture. You may have to try a few brands to see which one your cat likes
- Dehumidifier - These things are a blessing to remove humidity in the air, though at 90% you may have to empty the water basket often. Place one where you keep the litter box and keep windows closed.
- Air conditioners also help with removing moisture in the air.
- You can sprinkle some [ARM & HAMMER Cat Litter Deodorizer](http://www.armandhammer.com/pet-care/cat-care/Products/arm-and-hammer-cat-litter-deodorizer-powder.aspx) to reduce the smell, I find this stuff works great. Be sure to clean the litter box once to twice a day.

You tend to smell things easier when it's humid ([Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17901967)), which may be why the urine scent seems strong.

Answer (score -2):

Well one of your options is to put the litter box in a closed space where their are no windows. And having a small fan around the area can keep the weather less damp.

Comment: I am not sure this would work.  It would trap the ammonia in the small space and the only place for the humidity in the room to go, would be to get absorbed by the cat litter.  It going to be easier for more humidity to get in to the room then the cat.